# pass a List to a method that accepts a variable number of arguments

Tags: java

I am new to Java and got to access a legacy app that has a method like this which takes variable number of arguments.

```
  MarkEdges(edge1,edge2,edge3...){...}
```

where:

```
 Edge edge1 = new Edge(/*edge arguments go here*);
```

it works fine like that but I have a list of edges that I want to pass to MarkEdges:

```
 List<Edge> edges = new ArrayList();
 //populate the edges from a service then pass them for marking.
 MarkEdges(edges);
```

but I can't compile it. I was hoping for something like spread operator of JS.

Comment: You don't have an array, but a List ;) you wrote well in title, but mistake in post

Answer (score 1):

You have to use

```
MarkEdges(edges.toArray(new Edge[0]));
```